# Performing facebook searches with javascript API

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I have a user's email, and I would like to search for them in Facebook using the javascript api.

I know I need something

```
FB.api('/search', {q: 'user@email.com', type: 'user'}, function(response) {
    //Handle response
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work, I don't even get a response.

I have also tried putting it inside and/or after a call to `FB.login()` which just fails for some reason.

Any suggestions?  Their documentation for how to use this is so vague.

EDIT:

Here is all of the appropriate code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    FB.init({
        appId: 'apikey', //Actual API key removed for obvious reasons
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true, // parse XFBML
        oauth: true // enable OAuth 2.0
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/search', {q: 'user@email.com', type: 'user'}, function(response) {
            {
                alert(response);
            });
        }
        else {
            alert(response.toString());
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @alexela  Never did end up getting it working.

Answer (score 3):

```
var urlCall = "/search?q=Bamboo&type=page&access_token=";
FB.api(urlCall, function(response) {
  //you code to execute     
});
```

Finally found this after some digging.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing along an api key?

i would start here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

and then follow this example that uses 0Auth 2.0 to form the basis of how you will need to make your api requests: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/ (this article appears to be the most recent!)

Comment: I am calling FB.init using my app ID, is that what you mean?

Comment: yes. is there any more code that you can add in to your question? i'm wondering if there is anything beyond your FB.api() call that might be preventing this.

Comment: Added applicable source code to the question, Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for updating, but your code still does not seem to be complete. Do you have an fb-root div element? I am having trouble getting an api key (might be something wrong with the system) so i can't test like i wanted to.

Comment: Sorry, I had missed the fb-root div previously, I added it in, but I am still having problems